# Get rigidbody2d to go backwards

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm using Unity to make a simple Rtype-style game. I'm happy with rigidbody2d physics for my character sprite, except I want to be able to move backwards! Not sure how to do this with rigidbody physics? Is there a way to make the down arrow accelerate the sprite backwards? My code is as follows:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Fighter_movement : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float thrust;
    public float drag;
    public Rigidbody2D rb;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        Vector2 movement = new Vector2(moveHorizontal, moveVertical);

        rb.AddForce(movement);

    }
}
```

Comment: "Is there a way to make the down arrow accelerate the sprite backwards?" Do you mean the left arrow? You code should be working as far as I can see.

Comment: Ah no I mean the down arrow. Left arrow moves it left, right arrow right - up arrow adds thrust, but I need -ve thrust - it's not quite like R-Type in that forward is up

Comment: Ah Ok, a vertical scroller. Still your code should work. Input.GetAxis returns a value from -1 (down or left) to 1 (right or up). Does your code work to move the sprite in any direction at all? You might need to multiply the Input.GetAxis value to add more force.

Comment: What you say sounds right - that's how I interpreted the code when I copied the script - but it works to move the sprite left, right or up, but not down?

Comment: Put Debug.Log(movement) in FixedUpdate. What do you see when you press down? Also, what gravity settings have you for the level (Project Settings Physics > Gravity if I remember correctly).

Comment: Debug.Log(movement); gives me (0.0,0.0) when I press down only. When I press up I get (0.0, 0.1), and when I press left I get (-0.1, 0.0) and right (0.1, 0.0)

Comment: I have gravity set to 0, but I guess I don't want gravity to exist - not for it just to have a value of 0?

Comment: So your input is not working properly. Try checking the hardware and your input settings. Yeah gravity 0 is OK.